# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - Authorize Attribute not working without Policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1, authorize-attribute

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Api project that uses custom HMAC Authentication. The Authentication is identifying the user successfully.

I am using Policies on several of my controller actions (for limited access) and there is one controller action where I want to Allow Anonymous access.  All other controller actions should just require the user to be authenticated (general access).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{              
    services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsOrCloseAttribute());
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddAuthentication(HmacAuthenticationDefaults.Scheme)
            .AddHmacAuthentication();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
        options.AddPolicy("Historian", policy => policy.RequireRole("Historian"));
    });
}
```

Here is a sample controller, where the first action uses the Policy `Historian`, which works and will return successfully.
The second action, that just uses the base `Authorize` attribute, returns unauthorized for the same user.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EventsController : ControllerBase
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "Historian")]
    [Route("Source/{sourceKey:int}/First")]
    public IActionResult Returns200(int sourceKey)
    {
        //return a result
    }

    [Authorize]
    [Route("Source/{sourceKey:int}/Last")]
    public IActionResult Returns401(int sourceKey)
    {
        //return a result
    }
}
```

I tried setting the DefaultPolicy under `AddAuthorization`, but that didn't help.  I really don't want to have to create a "GeneralAccess" policy and would rather just use the `Authorize` attribute to designate that.
Why is the `Authorize` attribute without a policy returning a 401?

Comment: How did you achieve `AddHmacAuthentication`? I could not reproduce your issue with `Asp.Net Core Identity`, try to share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: I excluded the `HmacAuthentication` code because its custom and it would have overwhelmed this question.    The User is successfully authenticated using that Hmac code, so I didn't see the value.  The authorization is where I believe the problem is at.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue with `Asp.Net Core Identity`?